# Respaldo de la parte fisica de una Base en Sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2000

estoy necesitando hacer, un respaldo de mi base de datos en sql server 2000, pero solo de la parte fisica, ya que modifique unas tablas, y agregue unos nuevos SP , bueno muchas gracias desde ya, muy contento con esta comunidad. Saludos

Comment: Me alegro que estés muy contento con esta comunidad. Hay mucha gente dispuesta a ayudarte aquí. Solo te diré que en este caso, se apreciaría mas detalles para entender mejor la pregunta. Porque, de hecho, no hay pregunta por ahora. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Donde estás teniendo problemas? Y te aviso que puede que sea un poco difícil contestarte de forma precisa con respecto a SQL Server 2000, ya que es una versión bien viejita. Pero ya veremos...

Comment: Ha que te refieres con la parte fisica? Los archivos mdf y ldf o de los datos

Comment: jaja si, ya es viejita, muchas gracias por responder, mi pregunta seria, Como hacer una copia de respaldo de los procedimientos y la parte fisica de las tablas, lo que son los datos no necesito respaldarlos. Nose si me explique bien, muchas gracias, y saludos.

Comment: @Byron si asi es, yo me pregunto si puedo respaldar uno de los dos archivos o asi mismo por separado, para no sobreescribir los datos de la otra base donde voy a poner la copia de respaldo, yo tengo una base en mi pc y la otra está implantada en un negocio y no puedo tocarle los datos solo, los procedimientos y la parte fisica, que hasta ahora la estaba modificando con Erwin.

Comment: @Rober, lo que necesitas no es un respaldo, el respaldo incluye todo (definición de las estructuras, programas, datos, estructuras de soporte como índices, etc.). Estas sufriendo lo que en StackOverflow se llama [el problema XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), que es que no estás preguntando sobre tu problema, sino sobre lo que tu crees que es la solución a tu problema. Te sugiero mejor preguntar directamente sobre tu problema, pues la solución va por otro lado. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate Gracias! , mi problema, es que yo tengo que migrar mi base de datos a otra, sin alterar los datos ya que la otra base está en uso, muchas gracias por la sugerencia, desde ya agradecido, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es generar un script de la base de datos, solo de las estructuras(tablas, procedimientos almacenados, funciones, etc) existen herramientas como [Oracle Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html), que permiten hacer ingenieria inversa a la base de datos y obtener un script del DDL.

En [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27122/Side-by-Side-SQL-Comparer-in-C) existe una aplicacion para comparar archivos con T-SQL que tambien podria ayudar

Comment: gracias por tu aporte bro, ya voy a buscar sas herramientas, para ver como puedo hacer, muchas gracias por el porte!, saludos.